# Is there any reason to test Difference-in-Differences if paralell trend is weakly violated?

Tags: econometrics

Normally when testing the parallel trend assumption in the Difference-in-Differences setting, we normally conduct the joint null test for the coefficients of pre-treatment periods. Normally, while the p-value of this test is higher than 0.1, so the parallel is satisfied. I am wondering if p-value of this test is 0.0979, whether I have any reason to conduct the Difference-in-Differences test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.05 is the standard for significance in economics. In that sense, the difference in pre-trends is insignificant. Nevertheless, you are justified in being concerned.

You may consider adding in individual-specific pre-trends to account for this. A concern is that your treatment response may be dynamic, in which case the individual-specific trends will absorb some of the treatment effect. See [Meer and West (2015)](http://jhr.uwpress.org/content/early/2015/11/20/jhr.51.2.0414-6298R1.abstract).

Comment: so, you mean, if p-value of joint null test is higher than 0.05, so the parallel trend assumption being satisfied ? Is there any reference for that, I am of really curiousity

Comment: I mean, if your null hypothesis is "Parallel trends is true" and you use the 5% level of significance, then you fail to reject the null if the p-value is .0979. That's just basic statistics. I don't think you need a reference. Perhaps I misunderstand.

Comment: I mean, it is joint null test, and the "Parallel trend is true " equal to the coefficients of joint null test should insignificant different from 0. So, it means that if the null test is true, p-value should be higher than 0.05 if you set 5% level of significance

Comment: The reference is here https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/47157/what-are-the-hypothesis-and-results-explaination-of-joint-null-test